# commenting nested parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, coding-style, comments, styles

It's very common in javascript to have the following:

```
function A (options, aaa, bbb) {
  var ccc = options.ccc;
  var ddd = options.ddd;
}
```

And currently I'm commenting it as such:

```
/**
 * a completely useless function
 *
 * @param {Object} options where options.ccc is {Number} ccc and options.ddd is {String} ddd
 * @param {Boolean} aaa
 * @param {String} bbb
 */
```

I'm unhappy with the way I describe the attributes in the options parameter

Is there a clean way to put them in the "{Type} description" pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I usually put a TAB or two after the variable's name ... before the description. I agree though... I'm not a huge fan either. But, this is how jsdocs processes it. If you fuddle with the formatting too much you may not get proper docs parsed out.

```
/**
 * SLP.Modules.Codes extends the SLP.Modules object on DOM-ready.
 * @module Codes
 */
SLP.Modules.Codes = {
    /**
     * First validate for empty fields, then check the campaign codes,
     * making sure that they begin with T(oyota), L(exus), or S(cion).
     * @param  {object} event   jQuery Event object (form submit)
     * @return {boolean}        true if all validation passes.
     */
    validateCampaignCodes: function(event){
        var $input, isValid = SLP.validateFormInputsNotEmpty(event);
        if (isValid) {// Continue validation if all fields are non-empty.
            $input = $("input").filter("[name=campaign_code]").each(function(){
                if (!(isValid = /^[TLS]/i.test(this.value))) {
                    return !SLP.DOM.$modalPrompt.find(".modal-body").html( // Error msg.
                        "Campaign Codes must begin with T(oyota), S(cion), or L(exus)."
                    ).end().modal("show");// On error, immediately exit (the each method).
                }
            });
        }
        // Convert campaign codes to uppercase for submission.
        $input.val(function(i,v){ return v.toUpperCase(); });
        // Enable all checkboxes to submit values with form.
        $("input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled", false);
        return isValid;
    },
```

Comment: care to post an example or two how you are doing it?